# ASIHTTPRequest vs AFNetworking framework for simple data post

Tags: ios, asihttprequest, afnetworking

I have tried `ASIHTTTPRequest` for a iOS App. `ASIHTTPRequest` does not support `ARC`. I heard about `AFNetworking` framework is newer than  `ASIHTTPRequest`. Is it reliable to use in an app for post data?

Comment: Yes you should use `AFNetworking`, as ASIHTTPRequest is an old framework and the development, or updation of framework is stopped. Plus `AFNetworking` is a very good framework..

Comment: ASIHTTPRequest is good but it is not maintained any more, I have been using it and still some of my code thats in production has ASIHTTP but  AFNetworking is better.

Answer (score 2):

As iphonic and satheeshwaran say's  `AFNetworking` better then `ASIHTTP` bellow is a good example of `AFNetworking` that how to use in Project and how it work. please follow this Bellow Example its very easy to use.

http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/ios-sdk_afnetworking/